# Power BI report translation and embedding (title, column names)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I just begun working on a project and have been tasked with translating some reports. I have found a handful of ways ranging from manual dataset translation to scripts and such. I was wondering, if there is some way of automating this process. Is there a way of taking an existing dataset, running some commands or something and with a few steps, have a translated report. My team has these reports embedded and there is a language code in the URL, perhaps there is some way of making use of that.

The dataset, that I am testing and trying to get it to translate consists of 4 tables and column names are only values with text, everything else is numbers. Logically, numbers don't translate, so columns are only necessary. There are also some visual titles, that should be translated.

I appreciate any help and any efforts made to resolve this.

Comment: Probably you should not make copies of the report in each language, but change the report to be multi-language itself. Check [this session](https://www.powerbidevcamp.net/sessions/session30/) by Ted Pattison. It explain in details what you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an embedded report, there's a couple of things that you can do:

- Use translations files in the PBI model to handle measures and column names.  These will show up as labels in visuals.  See the section, `Translate Power BI field and table names`, here: https://pbi-guy.com/tag/tabular-editor/
- The language can be selected from the app by putting it in a querystring: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Setting-language-and-locale-for-embedded-report/td-p/606714
- Add a table with translations for labels and titles.  See this section from the same link above: `Create one report and a “translation table” to display the right language`.  Note that a filter will need to be set by the app to select the language in addition to how the language is set in the querystring above.

A couple of important caveats:

- Anything overwritten in the report will override a translation.  So if you change a column name in a visual, that's what it will always be no matter what language is selected.
- Not every visual supports expressions, so sometimes you'll have to wrangle a button or multi-row card to use as a label or title.
- the free version of tabular editor can be found here: https://github.com/TabularEditor/TabularEditor/releases/tag/2.17.2

Comment: It would be nice to be able to pass translations as json like we can do with themes and embedded configuration. This way a customer can change it's own translations on report load instead of going though update translations and republish reports