# Why are measure names not translated in public PBI reports embedded using 'Publish to web' option?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

Public PBI report doesn't translate measure names

The embedded report does show translations for some innate PBI words like "and" and "by" in a visual header or Million shortening in numbers, but it leaves measure names untranslated.

It does translate the measure names when the report is viewed under a PBI account: both in Power BI cloud user interface and via the link in "File > Embed report > Website or portal". But this option requires a user to log-in to view the report. The problem appears when I select "File > Embed report >  Publish to web (public)".

I was given a task to localize a demo report for different language versions of our website.

The report is made in Power BI Desktop Version: 2.116.966.0 64-bit (April 2023). I added measure translations via Tabular Editor and published it from an account with Premium per User license. As I mentioned above, the translations do appear in the cloud (based on browser's locale settings as far as I see).

Then I select "File > Embed report >  Publish to web (public)" option, copy the link, append "&language=ru&formatlocale=ru-RU" at the end and expect to see a translated report, but only words "and", "by", "M" (million) get translated.
I tried it via edge, firefox, brave. If a browser has locale set, the same effect appears without appending anything. Just "&language=ru" and "&language=ru-RU" give the same result.

Of course, I can create several versions of the report for each language. But is it the only option?

Comment: Let's take an example: while programming in JavaScript, if you create a variable like "Sum," it won't automatically update when you change your IDE's language (some user also use gibberish variable names). Similarly, in Power BI, we use measure and column names. If you're interested in making your reports multilingual, check out this helpful document on [Multilingual Reports in Power BI](https://pbi-guy.com/2022/01/31/multilingual-reports-in-power-bi/). I don't think it's a supported feature now. You can submit your idea [here](https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/)

Comment: @RahulRoy I have used exactly the last method described in your article. And my translations do appear in PBI cloud. They do not appear only in *public embedded* report.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434577/power-bi-report-translation-and-embedding-title-column-names